# How to capture Result from InvokeAsync

Tags: asynchronous

I'm trying to make async call with WSDL that belongs to SIRI (SIRI
Service Interface for Real Time Information), How can I "catch" the response if I call "GetStopMonitoringServiceAsync" ?

Relevant part from the WSDL:

```
public void GetStopMonitoringServiceAsync(ServiceRequestStructure Request) {
        this.GetStopMonitoringServiceAsync(Request, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void GetStopMonitoringServiceAsync(ServiceRequestStructure Request, object userState) {
        if ((this.GetStopMonitoringServiceOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.GetStopMonitoringServiceOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnGetStopMonitoringServiceOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("GetStopMonitoringService", new object[] {
                    Request}, this.GetStopMonitoringServiceOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnGetStopMonitoringServiceOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.GetStopMonitoringServiceCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.GetStopMonitoringServiceCompleted(this, new GetStopMonitoringServiceCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public new void CancelAsync(object userState) {
        base.CancelAsync(userState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed..

```
SS.GetStopMonitoringServiceCompleted += new GetStopMonitoringServiceCompletedEventHandler(GetStopMonitoringServiceCompletedEventHandler);


static void GetStopMonitoringServiceCompletedEventHandler(object sender, GetStopMonitoringServiceCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceDeliveryStructure Response = new ServiceDeliveryStructure();
            Response = e.Result;
        }
```